# azure search complex field filter

Tags: azure, search

I am trying to filter the hotel data present in azure search samples I am not able to filter on the address field

$filter=Address/City eq 'San Antonio'

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples

Loaded the data using the sample  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples/tree/main/quickstart/v11

tried filtering on city  StreetAddress it does not seem to be working

$filter=Address/City eq 'San Antonio'

$filter=Address/StreetAddress eq '677 5th Ave'

none of it seems to be working can you please let me know what iam doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the sample repository and tried the following code which worked for me:

```
            options = new SearchOptions()
            {
                IncludeTotalCount = true,
                Filter = "Address/City eq 'San Antonio'",
                OrderBy = { "" }
            };

            options.Select.Add("HotelId");
            options.Select.Add("HotelName");
            options.Select.Add("Rating");

            response = srchclient.Search<Hotel>("*", options);
            WriteDocuments(response);
```

Comment: No it still giving all

Comment: Edited my answer with working code.

Comment: Thanks its working through code but not via portal $filter=Address/City eq 'San Antonio' or Address/City eq 'Sarasota'

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the screenshot of the portal? Are you putting `$filter=Address/City eq 'San Antonio'` in the search text box there? If that's the case, then it won't work. That field is for search criteria only. Filter is completely different.

Comment: Yes but iam able to filter all other filter fields  like category $filter=Category eq 'Resort and Spa'